# Is there a way to obtain the chat messages of a dailymotion live stream?

Tags: dailymotion-api

I would like to extract live chat messages and show in my live stream. Just like  twitch can do.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, there is no way to connect to the Dailymotion Games chat for now.